# Oracle ADB TLS connection error in Tomcat

Tags: oracle, tomcat9, mtls, oracle-wallet

It fails with different errors when I connect to an OCI ADB instance from a Tomcat-hosted [version 9.0.65] / [jdk8 - 202 build] application using the TLS mechanism. However, when I download the Wallet file and set the JVM argument with the wallet location it works-
The code snippet below

```
PoolDataSource ds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
        try {
            ds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
            ds.setURL(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description= (address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1521)(host=ip.address.of.adb))(connect_data=(service_name=$service_name))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=no)))");
            ds.setUser("myUser");
            ds.setPassword("********");
            ds.setInitialPoolSize(5);
            ds.setMinPoolSize(5);
            ds.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error occurred while trying to configure datasource");
        }
```

it works with following wallet VM args

```
-Doracle.net.wallet_location=/path/to/wallet
-Doracle.net.tns_admin=/path/to/wallet
```

An example of an error is when I don't set the wallet location. I need a TLS connection only and not the wallet

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize the trust store.
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.trustStoreFailure(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:766)
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:417)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:792)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:57)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:71)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.loadFileBasedKeyStore(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:1153)
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.loadKeyStore(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:1125)
    at oracle.net.nt.CustomSSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(CustomSSLSocketFactory.java:408)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:790)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: Wallets are required for ADB connections. They contain the certs necessary to establish the connection.

Comment: The ADB TLS connection doesn't need certificates or a Wallet with jks files. 
My tomcat was configured with -

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore= my private certificate 
```
when I removed it, the app connected with the ADB without issues.
However, if you need to specify the trutsStore, then import the oracle certificate from the wallet to your local trust store and also pass the password to your local trustStore 

```
 javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword= my-password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ADB TLS connection doesn't need certificates or a Wallet with jks files.
My tomcat was configured with -

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore= my private certificate
```

when I removed it, the app connected with the ADB without issues.
However, if you need to specify the trutsStore, then import the oracle certificate from the wallet to your local trust store and also pass the password to your local trustStore

```
 javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword= my-password
```